# Geb: Element is no longer attached to the DOM inside waitFor

Tags: grails, selenium, geb

I am getting an "Element is no longer attached to the DOM" error from Geb tests.  The thing that's confusing me is that the error is from within `waitFor` itself -- I inserted the wait specifically to allow the async activity on the page to complete before moving ahead with clicking a link, which was previously the source of the same error.  If the wait itself fails, now I'm at a loss.

The code is something like

```
waitFor { $("div", text: "... search string ... ") }
$("a", id: "element-id").click()
```

and the stack trace shows that the waitFor itself is actually the problem:

```
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getText(RemoteWebElement.java:152)
at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.matches_closure28(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:474)
at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.matches(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:471)
at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.filter_closure2(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:63)
at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.filter(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:63)
at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.find(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:48)
at geb.content.NavigableSupport.$(NavigableSupport.groovy:96)
at geb.Browser.methodMissing(Browser.groovy:193)
at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:51)
at [my test]_closure7([my test].groovy:147)
at [my test]_closure7([my test].groovy)
at geb.waiting.Wait.waitFor(Wait.groovy:106)
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace

Answer (score 2):

From the stacktrace I can see that you use that selector inside of a test class and not a module so the possibility of a module base element being detached can be ruled out.

If this is happening consistently for you then it means that one of the elements selected by the `div` selector gets removed from DOM before its text is being retrieved to filter on it.

There are two reasons why this can happen:

- Your selector is very slow - selecting all div elements in a page and then filtering them based on text in the JVM can take a lot of time. Assuming that you use the default waiting preset then if that selector takes more than 5 seconds then the `waitFor {}` block will simply run once, get the exception and never retry because it runs out of time. You should do as much filtering as possible in the browser, that is use a CSS3 compatible selector and use Geb's text filtering extension on an as small as possible element set.
- Your page is async in a periodic way and it changes quicker than the selector is able to filter based on element text. This would be again possible because your selector looks like it could be potentially very slow.

Basically I would suggest coming up with a more specific selector than what you have there currently.